# ABCUpload4.XField.4 error 80040041

Tags: asp-classic

ABCUpload4.XField.4 error 80040041

A Windows error-Network access denied - (0x0000041) occurred.

/html/er/community_suggestion.asp,line 126

I got an error recently,found this error after i click upload button,i have several pages using this method to upload picture,only this page having error when i upload picture.

Comment: some coding examples would help! Like what is stated in (and around) line 126?

Comment: Looks like permissions on where you are trying to upload to

Comment: Further to Janusz's point above it looks like you need to give your website's IUSR account permission to write to the upload directory specified in line 126.  Another possibility is that you do have permission to write to the directory but there's already a file there with the same name and you don't have permission to overwrite it.

Comment: hi john,i checked the directory,no same picture name,and the directory is given full control permission

Answer (score 0):

if gs_enable_imp = true then
        theForm.SetUser gs_imp_username, gs_imp_password
  end if

i forgot include this....my abd